# Volume integral of the gradient of a scalar field.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate the volume integral of the gradient of a scalar field, which would give a vector as the answer. Is there any formula? As far as I can recall, maybe I can write
$$\int_\Omega \nabla P \text{d}V = \int_{\partial\Omega} P\hat{n}\text{d}\sigma$$

where $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of the volume $\Omega$ and $\hat{n}$ is the outward pointing normal vector.

But more importantly, what does it follow from? Does this follow directly from one of the integral theorems, or how can it be proved independently?

Answer (score 1):

This is true, it is a result of Gauss' divergence theorem. Consider any constant vector $\vec{c}$, then apply the divergence theorem to the vector field $\vec{F} := P\vec{c}$. You will obtain the following volume integral
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot F \,dV = \int_{\Omega} P (\nabla \vec{c}) + \nabla P \cdot \vec{c} \,dV = \int_{\Omega} \nabla P\cdot \vec{c} \,dV = \int_{\Omega} \nabla P \,dV \cdot \vec{c}$$
using respectively the product rule for the divergence, the fact that the divergence of a constant vector is zero, and the linearity of the integral.

Similarly for the surface integral of the divergence theorem
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} F\cdot \hat{n}dA = \int_{\partial\Omega} P(\vec{c}\cdot\vec{n})d\sigma = \int_{\partial\Omega}P\hat{n}d\sigma \cdot \vec{c}.$$
Then the Gauss divergence theorem states
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla P \,dV \cdot \vec{c} = \int_{\partial\Omega}P\hat{n}d\sigma \cdot \vec{c}.$$
As this result holds for any vector $\vec{c}$, the two terms must be equal.

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla P \,dV = \int_{\partial\Omega}P\hat{n}d\sigma.$$